# Can you use cvCalibrateCamera2 to find the extrinsic relationship between two cameras?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision

I'm wondering what the possibility of using `cvCalibrateCamera2` to find the rotation and translation between 2 cameras is.

Take, for example, the scenario where you have just done a chessboard calibration where the chessboard was viewable to both image planes.  If I then pass in those points from one camera as the `object_points` and the points from the other camera as the `image_points` would this give me the rotation and translation between the two views?

Also, this spits out several rotation matrices and translation vectors.  Which one would I use?

Answer (score 0):

I think [StereoCalibrate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate) is probably a better match for your needs. You'll need to provide a set of 2D correspondences as well as both cameras' intrinsics which you already know from the chessboard calibration.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use `FindExtrinsicCameraParams2`

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findextrinsiccameraparams2