# Calibrate two Cameras OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm using OpenCV 2.2 and I'm trying to calibrate two cameras to view along the same co-ordinate system. The two cameras will be placed a little separate from each other. I understand calibrating intrinsics for a single camera, but am a little confused so as to how I'd be able to combine two cameras together. Follow up questions are good too.

Cheers.

EDIT - Am working on this problem - will post and describe what works for me when I get it done.

Comment: Please detail what you mean by 'calibrate'

Comment: I want it to be so that when I have both cameras pointed towards the same area, I know exactly how their systems of co-ordinates correspond with each other. If I see a ball through both those cameras, I want my program to be able to understand that they are seeing the same thing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597025/can-you-use-cvcalibratecamera2-to-find-the-extrinsic-relationship-between-two-cam/)? My answer from that is [StereoCalibrate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate) will allow you to solve for the essential matrix which you can use to relate any point in one camera to a point in the other camera.

Comment: So does StereoCalibrate just end up treating the two cameras as two streams for the same camera?

Comment: No, it assumes it's two separate cameras. This is reflected in the fact that the function takes two different sets of intrinsics.

Comment: Once the intrinsics, extrinsics and essential matrix are found, how to I convert one point (x, y) from one camera to the other camera's coordinate system?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have two cameras C1 and C2.

1. The *fundamental matrix* F defines the relation between the two cameras, that means given an image point x1 in C1 how it constrains the position of the corresponding point x2 in C2. The answer: x1 defines a *line* in C2 and x2 *must* be on this line. That is [epipolar geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry). It is defined just by the cameras parameters and it does *not* depend on the scene geometry at all.
2. Suppose now you have the two *projective matrices*, P1 and P2, ie, you know all parameters for both cameras. If you have a pair of *correspondences*, x1 <-> x2 (x1 from C1 and x2 from C2), you are able to estimate the 3D location of the point X in space that was imaged to x1 in C1 and to x2 in C2. You are able to *reconstruct your ball*, getting a 3D model. *The tricky part is to find the matches x1 <-> x2*.

Now, if your problem is to know if C1 and C2 are seeing the same thing, maybe your problem is not a *stereo problem*, but a *recognition problem*. Maybe [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) or [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF) algorithms be a more appropriated approach.

Comment: If you provide a set of correspondences x1 <-> x2, the fundamental matrix can be estimated. Take a look on *cvFindFundamentalMat* in OpenCV API.

Comment: Chapter 12 of the *Learning OpenCV* book presents a gentle introduction to the subject. It presents a good balance between theory and hands-on with OpenCV routines. For all the gory details, the reference is Hartley and Zisserman book *Multile view geometry in computer vision*.

Comment: "It is defined just by the cameras parameters and it does not depend on the scene geometry at all." - This is not entirely true. Explicit knowledge of the scene geometry is not needed to calculate the fundamental matrix, but changing the pose of a camera will invalidate it (i.e. if the baseline changes).

Comment: Once the fundamental matrix is determined, how can I find the corresponding x2 ( x, y) for x1?